# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat adding 12mins when output format is g:ma

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to split/convert two 24hr times to individual 12hr times, but PHP seems to be adding either 12mins or 1min to the output, and I can't determine the cause, after trying timezone and system time fixes. Could you please educate me?

Input:

```
<?php $timeSlot = ["10:00","22:00"];
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$timeSlot[0])->format('H:i');
    echo " - ";
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$timeSlot[1])->format('H:i');
    echo " Fine.<br>";
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$timeSlot[0])->format('g:ma');
    echo " - ";
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$timeSlot[1],new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'))->format('g:ma');
    echo " Why 12 extra minutes?<br>";
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i',$timeSlot[0])->format('g:ma');
    echo " - ";
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i',$timeSlot[1],new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'))->format('g:ma'); 
    echo " Why one extra minute?"; ?>
```

Output:

```
10:00 - 22:00 Fine.
10:12am - 10:12pm Why 12 extra minutes?
10:01am - 10:01pm Why one extra minute?
```

Comment: Man, that was a trick question. Were you trying to fool us or who gave you that code to fool you? ;)

Comment: Yep, this was a dumb question, damn format codes got me again. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't getting extra minutes.  You are displaying the number for the month (12 for December).  Change the format to `g:ia`

When you did `!H:i` you are setting the month, day, and year to the Unix epoch which would be Jan. 1, 1970.  Hence you are seeing a `01` for January in those settings.

See the table here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php